# Is good practice to pass state as props to children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I find myself aggregating the state on one component. Normally the node I know I will re-render so changes can propagate and state is not all over the place. Lately, I've found myself passing the state of this component as props to its first children using [JSX spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) for the most part. Just to be absolutely clear, this is what I mean:

```js
var Child = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    this.props.owner.setState({
      count: this.props.count + 1,
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.count}</div>;
  }  
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      count: 0,
      owner: this
    };
  },
  render: function(){
    return <Child {...this.state}/>
  }
});
```

And it works (http://jsbin.com/xugurugebu/edit?html,js,output), you can always go back to this component to understand whats going on and keep state as minimal as possible.

So the actual question is, if that is/isn't a good practice and why.

The downside I can think about at the moment is that with this approach maybe every child component would always re-render when there is a state change on the owner, if that's the case I think the above is something to use on small Component trees.

Comment: It isn't very prescriptive and easy to follow what's being sent to the children when the parent is passing all local state as you've done with spread attributes. In fact, depending on the complexity of the component, it may be difficult to reason about what's being sent. I'd also be surprised that the child actually needs all of the parent's state.

Comment: Yes, that would depend on the situation. To see what is being sent you just have to look at the parent. The reason why I like this is that is clear from where the state comes and renders from.

Comment: If the parent is defined locally, it's easy. But as a project grows in scope, and a component is used by multiple types of parents, the challenge could magnify.

Comment: Yeah, for "nearby" components is fine. Though to track down props propagating from one component to the next on a large hierarchy would be less easy that to look at `this.props.owner` from the component you are in any case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes!

State should only be set on the top level element, this ensures that data only ever flows one way through your components.

Bear in mind, React will only render the changes that have been made since the last render, if parts of your child elements haven't been modified they will not be re-rendered to the DOM.

React has a section in their docs titled [lifting up state](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up).

Comment: Right! I didn't thought of the diffs. So what you are saying is that the diff algorithm will take care of making sense of re-renders so even if it propagates it will only make sure to re-render to the DOM those that **actually** have some change. I think that if this sticks I'll will measure stuff and do so perf to se what happens with this approach.

Comment: @stringparser Correct. React uses a virtual DOM to diff any changes against. Then these changes, and only these changes are to be rendered to the real DOM. There are a number of React rendering tests on jsperf such as http://jsperf.com/react-vs-pure-js/9

Comment: Although I agree on this and I do it all the time, I find this phrase in this post interesting https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html "is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t state.